# Why is there a need for an eNVM and an eSRAM in the same SoC FPGA

Tags: fpga, memory, sram, non-volatile-memory, microsemi-fpga

SmartFusion2 SoC FPGA is distinguished by containing an embedded Non-Volatile-Memory (eNVM) that is used to store the code needed for the booting process of the FPGA after power up. So in the presence of this Flash memory why do we still need the eSRAM ?

[image]

Comment: Just a guess, but have you compared the timing specs of the eNVM vs the SRAM?

Comment: It looks like you're answering your own question (in the text).

Answer (score 2):

eNVM is nonvolatile and has a limited number of write cycles.

eSRAM is volatile and has an effectively infinite number of write cycles. (Probably much faster, too.)

A typical application needs both kinds of memory.

Comment: It also sounds *a little bit* like partitioning on your computer. "*Why do you have several partitions? Why C and D? Why not just C?*". - Still, good answer.

Answer (score 2):

eSRAM is likely a lot faster, and as it is SRAM it can be written an unlimited number of times.  Think of the eNVM as the hard drive/SSD and the eSRAM as the RAM.